# Firefox (multiple versions) aligns div to the right

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

Given the following CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Corbel, Calibri, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;'
}
.heb {
    font-family: Bwhebb;
}
.heb, .eng {
    font-size: 25pt;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
}
.slideshow, .cardface, .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and the following HTML

```
<div class="card" id="wordID">
    <span class='heb cardface'>
        some word
    </span>
    <br />
    <div class='eng cardface'>
        some translation
        <br />
        <a href='#' class='right' >correct</a> | 
        <a href='#' class='wrong' >incorrect</a>
    </div>            
</div>
```

I get two different results on Chrome and Firefox. Chrome centers everything on the page while Firefox places the span .heb .cardface WAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY to the right.

I am pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, could you help me figure it out?

Comment: Instead of having `.card` as `position:absolute;`, trying having it as `position:relative;` with a `margin:0 auto;` applied to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remove `position: absolute;` from your CSS, in the last line, having `.slideshow, .cardface, .card {width: 100%; height: 15%; text-align: center;}`, it is all centered.

[Is that what you're after?](http://jsfiddle.net/ym3fm/)

Comment: You also removed the `display:none;`

Comment: I was just stating it because I didn't notice at first :P

Answer (score 2):

You have an absolutely positioned div with an auto left offset.  That means its left edge should be placed where it would go if its position were static.... and since the parent element has centered text, that means at the center of the parent element.  Chrome gets this right if you have any text in the parent element, but wrong if the parent element has only positioned kids.  See the testcases at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671491

Oh, and the upshot is that `left: 0` should do what you want, I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in firefox is that `<div class="card" id="wordID">`  is in absolute position, and `<span class='heb cardface'>some word</span>` is also in absolute position.

You can either remove the absolute positionning, according to @Nightfirecat suggestion.

Or you can remove the absolute positionning for either `.card` or `.cardface`. It's better if you remove it from `.cardface`, since then, `.card` content will be what's inside `.cardface` (Remember : Positionning something in absolute moves it out of it context! Aka, the parent element won't use it to define it's size/will act quirky.)